# How could I group multiple arrays into hash

Tags: ruby

I want to know is there more elegant way to acheive my goal.

## Input data

- all users : [1,2,3]
- all products : [4,5,7]
- view history    `[[1, 7],[2, 4], [1, 4], [1, 4]]`

  - each items means which user brosed which product
  - Structure: `[[USER_ID, PRODUCT_ID], [USER_ID, PRODUCT_ID], ..]`

## expect output

```
{   
    1:{
        4:2,
        5:0,
        7:1,
    },
    2:{
        4:1,
        5:0,
        7:0,
    },    
    3:{
        4:0,
        5:0,
        7:0,
    }

}

{
    USER_ID:{
        PRODUCIT_ID: view_count
        ...
    },
    USER_ID:{
        PRODUCIT_ID: view_count,
        ...
    },
}
```

Comment: I give up. What's the rule that generates the output? (I thought I had it until I got to `3:{ 4:0`, where I was expecting `3:{ 4:1`). OK, I've got what for you: what's the next number in the sequence `1, 2, 4, 7, 12, 20, 33...`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland User `3` has 0 views of product `4`.

Comment: `my %h; for my $u (@users) { $h{$u} = { map +($_ => 0), @products }; } for my $v (@views) { $h{$v->[0]}{$v->[1]}++; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
users = [1,2,3]
prods = [4,5,7]
history = [[1, 7],[2, 4], [1, 4], [1, 4]]

# will prepare hash values
ph = prods.zip([0] * prods.size).to_h
# will prepare resulting hash
res = users.map { |u| [u, ph.dup] }.to_h

# walk through history and update res
history.inject(res) do |memo, u| 
  memo[u.first][u.last] += 1
  memo 
end


#=> {
#  1 => {
#    4 => 2,
#    5 => 0,
#    7 => 1
#  },
#  2 => {
#    4 => 1,
#    5 => 0,
#    7 => 0
#  },
#  3 => {
#    4 => 0,
#    5 => 0,
#    7 => 0
#  }
#}
```

Answer (score 0):

A short solution tried with Ruby 1.8.7.

```
view_history = [[1, 7],[2, 4], [1, 4], [1, 4]] 
Hash[*view_history.group_by(&:first).
                   map { |k,v| [k,Hash[*v.group_by(&:last).
                                          map { |k,v| [k,v.size] }.
                                          flatten]] }.
                   flatten]
#=> {1=>{7=>1, 4=>2}, 2=>{4=>1}}
```

The solution does not contain products without any view.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my answer, but it looks so complicated

```
all_products = Product.all.pluck(:id).map{|c|[c,0]}.to_h
collaborative_matrix = view_history.group_by{|c| c.first}.collect do |user_id, raw_view_history|
  view_history = raw_view_history.collect{|c|c.last}
     .each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |word,counts| counts[word] += 1 }
  {
    user_id => view_history.merge(all_products) { |key, v1, v2| [v1, v2].max }
  }
end
```